# Publish/Unpublish module on a schedule

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module, extensions, module-manager

I look after a website which is run by a church and every 1st sunday of the month they have a slightly different service schedule. The site uses an image slider which rotates advising of the services that week, so I;ve been asked that for the 1st sunday of every week a different image be used within the slider - this may well get forgotten so i was thinking of a more automated solution.

I know there are timed content extensions out there but nothing which seems to publish/unpublish modules. My plan would be to have 2 image sliders one for the 1st week and 1 for the remaining 3 weeks, and possibly run a script on a cron job to publish/unpublish the respective modules based on the time of the month - so the cron would probably run every friday for example, the script would then check if the sunday was the first sunday of the month and if so publish/unpublish the modules.

First off, does anyone know of an extension that may already do this, secondly is my suggestion an acceptable solution to the problem - i.e. could it cause any problems security wise or in any other way?

Thank you in advance
Donna

Comment: there is always only 1 Sunday every week...

Comment: I know this is an older post, but I was looking for the same solution - I looked at the website listed but it didn't give a clear indication. Did this solve your problem in allowing for the auto changing of slider content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely have to look at [**Regular Labs: Advanced Module Manager Pro**](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager#free-vs-pro)

The pro version features Seasons, Months, Days, Time assignments, so you can schedule the appearance of your modules.

[image: AMMpro Day/Time Settings]

Comment: brilliant thank you. I'll take a look. I searched the JED but i could only find things relating to articles. I'll mark as the answer once i've checked the extension.